# Saving views in an MVC5 application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I currently have an MVC application that allows users to add and delete widgets and move them around to their liking within their dashboard.  I was wondering if it was possible to save the layout of their dashboard and load them when they revisit their dashboard?  I was thinking of taking the view and saving it on the server with a sql reference to that file.  Every time the user logs or goes back to their dashboard it will load from that cshtml file on the server?  Not sure if this was the best way(probably not).

Comment: In a similar style to Trello?

Comment: save the users data in tabular form db and when user come online then get their data from db and render the markup from single view by looping.

Comment: @SelectDistinct Yes like trello.

Comment: This has nothing to do with "saving" a layout. Trello stores the status and order of tasks as data. This data is used to calculate and render its display. Moving a task from one column to another actually records a status change to the database.